# How is a parameter change handled during recursion in Java?

Tags: java

Here is a recursive method:

```
private static int minimumTotal(List<List<Integer>> triangle, int index) { 
    if (triangle.isEmpty()) { 
        return 0; 
    } 

    List<Integer> row = triangle.remove(0); 

    int sum1 = row.get(index) + minimumTotal(triangle, index);
    int sum2 = row.get(index) + minimumTotal(triangle, index + 1);
    return Math.min(sum1, sum2); 
}
```

I want `sum1` and `sum2` to be calculated on the same `triangle` object. However, what happens is the following: after `sum1` is calculated, one row of `triangle` (and then another within the recursion and another ...). Now, when `sum2` is calculated it has a `triangle` that is empty!

1. This confuses me regarding how Java handles recursion. Why is the object `triangle` getting modified? I was under the assumption that it should be a "local" data at every recursion level.
2. How can we rewrite the code to get the desired behavior?

---

As an example, lets say the `triangle` object has two rows (given by two list of integers). `sum1` is supposed to get something from the first row and then recursively call the method on the `triangle` that has only one row remaining. Similarly, `sum2` is also supposed to get something from the first row and then recursively call the method on the `triangle` that has only one row remaining. However, what I see is the following. After `sum1` is computed, `triangle` is empty. Thus, `sum2` is assigned a wrong value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one `List<List<Integer>> triangle` instance. The reference to that instance is passed to each recursive call, but any change done to this instance is reflected in all levels of the recursion.

It looks like you want to process the next row of triangle in each recursive call, and you achieve it by removing the first row (so that the next recursive call has a different first row). If that's the case, you don't have to remove the first row. Just pass an index to the row, so that each recursive call knows which row it should work on.

```
private static int minimumTotal(List<List<Integer>> triangle, int rowIndex, int colIndex) { 
    if (rowIndex >= triangle.size()) { 
        return 0; 
    } 

    List<Integer> row = triangle.get(rowIndex); 

    int sum1 = row.get(colIndex) + minimumTotal(triangle, rowIndex + 1, colIndex);
    int sum2 = row.get(colIndex) + minimumTotal(triangle, rowIndex + 1, colIndex + 1);
    return Math.min(sum1, sum2); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found this solution most easy to implement and intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, everything except the primitive types (`int`, `boolean`, `char`, etc..) is a reference type. It means that what you actually hold in the variable is just a reference to the actual object. If you pass it to a method, the reference gets copied, but it still points to the same object in memory. That means that every call of your recursive method points to the same `triangle` object and since the first recursive call removes all the items from the `List`, the second call will always be given just the empty `List`.

The straightforward way would be to create a two duplicates of the `List` before each recursive call and passing references to those duplicates. This would, however, be a very time consuming and inefficient way.

I would suggest adding a third parameter to the recursive call saying where to start with the calculation. The method wouldn't change the original `triangle` in any way.

```
private static int minimumTotal(List<List<Integer>> triangle, int index, int from) { 
    if (from >= triangle.size()) { 
        return 0; 
    } 

    List<Integer> row = triangle.get(from); 

    int sum1 = row.get(index) + minimumTotal(triangle, index, from + 1);
    int sum2 = row.get(index) + minimumTotal(triangle, index + 1, from + 1);
    return Math.min(sum1, sum2); 
}
```

Your initial call would look like this:

```
minimumTotal(triangle, index, 0);
```

This method will even be faster than your original one, because `remove(0)` is an O(N) operation.

Comment: Almost correct, except you have to change the `if (triangle.isEmpty())` condition at the start to `if (from >= triangle.size())`. Otherwise, your recursion will end with `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing `triangle` parameter internal state here:

```
List<Integer> row = triangle.remove(0);
```

Since you're calling `minimumTotal` over and over, on every recursive call `triangle` losses a row. This is not related to how Java (or any other programming language) handles recursion, but about what you do in the recursive call.

If you only want/need to retrieve the element at position `0`, then use `triangle.get(0)`. If you need to be removed but only after doing the necessary operations on it, then call `triangle.remove` only after performing the desired actions. In case you don't remove any inner list of your `triangle`, then use `triangle.get(index)` and pass `index` as parameter.

Comment: Always using `triangle.get(0)` would lead to infinite recursion, since triangle being empty is what stops the recursion. If you don't modify `triangle`, you should introduce an additional parameter to the recursive method, in order for it to terminate.

Comment: @Eran if you call `triangle.remove(0)` (as stated in my answer previously to your comment) then the recursive call will end.

Comment: If you don't change `triangle` or `index` prior to the first recursive call - `minimumTotal(triangle, index)` - that call gets the exact same parameters as the previous level of the recursion, so the recursion can never end, regardless of whether or not you are removing the first row after that call.